# Cannot select input in Logic

Tags: logic-pro, input

I am using OS X 10.11 el capitan. Since there is no working driver for my USB-Interface (M-Audio Fast Track Pro) I uninstalled the driver to let my interface work as a class compliant device.

That works well. I can see the pitch in the OSX sound settings and can record in Quick Time and Adobe Audition. But when I want to use Logic the MIDI-Input just works fine but there is no input channel I can use for audio inputs (mic, guitar, etc).

Do you now any hints how to address the input channels in Logic correctly? I appreciate any answer.

EDIT:
This is how it looks in logic: [image: Logic - no input selectable]

And these are the inputs in Adobe Audition: [image: Audition - inputs available]

EDIT 2: This is what my input settings look like: [image: Logic input settings]

Comment: Here you are. I hope they help finding the problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my input settings above. Sorry for german labels...

Comment: For the moment I don't have a clue how to solve your problem, but perhaps you should select your soundcard also as the main output device. Just to see if that makes any changes... Also try to reinstall drivers this could definetely help. From what I know El Capitan has many issues with softwares. Did you upgraded your OS to El Capitan?

Comment: As I've already written in my question, the driver of my audio interface is incompatible with el capitan (upgraded from Yosemite). So I uninstalled the driver completely in order to let the interface work as class compliant (standard OSX USB Audio drivers). That works in the OSX settings, Audition and QuickTime but not in Logic. But I will have a try on the output device setting.

Comment: Sorry for the driver I didn't recorded the thing, give a try for the output tip and let us know. Now if the driver doesn t work on El capitan maybe you should consider downgrading to Yosemite (don't know if it is possible), but I think this be the reason of your problem. So make a mail to M-Audio or ask on a Mac forum how to solve the problem....